# Page breaking problem with exam.cls

Tags: page-breaking, exam

For some time, [version 2.01](http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/exam/exam.cls) of the [exam document class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) has been used in my department. In the future we are going to use the latest version (currently 2.4), and this has to be customised so that existing papers typeset as before. In the example below, the new version of `exam.cls` puts in an extra page break.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.8in} %set \textheight as in the old version
\extraheadheight[.7in]{-.2in}
%
\begin{document}
\hrule
\newpage
\showthe\textheight
\hrule
\vskip408pt
\hrule
\begin{center}
\rule{0.5\textwidth}{212pt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Our existing exam papers include the `\extraheadheight` command shown here. I expected setting `\textheight` to 8.8in (the value used by version 2.01 of `exam.cls`) and then including `\extraheadheight` to reproduce the behaviour of the old version, but in this case it does not.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I get a `\textheight` of 8.8in by removing the `\extraheadheight` command. Otherwise the text height is 9in.

Comment: @egreg --- the `\extraheadheight` is required for our purposes. I removed the headers from the example, to make it as minimal as possible. I can't reproduce the problem without `\extraheadheight`, though.

Comment: The final `\textheight` is 9in, so try setting it to 8.6in in the second line.

Comment: @egreg --- do you mean set it to 9in in the second line? Either way, I only get different behaviour from the two versions of `exam.cls` when I include `\extraheadheight`.

Comment: @egreg --- I've added some extra detail to clarify the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a vast odyssey through `source2e.pdf` and both versions of `exam.cls` (most of which was unnecessary) I bring you the following fix:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
 \patchcmd\@setheadheight{\endgroup}{\global\vsize=\textheight\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Perhaps some explanation is in order.  According to `exam.cls`, version 2.4, a bugfix was introduced in version 2.307beta (2009/03/28):

```
% We fixed a bug that arose only when the user used a figure or
% table environment that floated to the top of a page.  If that
% happened, then a full page's worth of text was placed below
% the figure or table, makeing the text run over the footline and off
% the bottom of the page.
%
% We fixed this by commenting out several lines at the end of
% \@setheadheight and @setfootheight.
```

The lines commented out included the one that sets `\vsize`.  Should you want them all, they are:

```
\global\@colroom=\textheight
\global\vsize=\textheight
\global\pagegoal=\textheight
```

Aside from minor changes in the structure of the code, that's the only difference between `\extraheadheight` in v2.4 and v2.01, and as you can see, it accounts for your bug:

```
\documentclass{exam}
% Comment out the next four lines to get 3 pages instead of 2 in v2.4
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
 \apptocmd\@setheadheight{\global\vsize=\textheight}{}{}
\makeatother
\extraheadheight[.7in]{-.2in}
\begin{document}
 \hrule
 \newpage
 \hrule
 \vskip408pt
 \hrule
 \begin{center}
  \rule{0.5\textwidth}{212pt}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Effectively, the old behavior you observe is considered incorrect and you can get it back by reinserting a bug that was removed three years ago!

Comment: If only I had checked the value of `\vsize`! I'll add a `keepoldpagebreaks` option to our customised class, but I won't restore the behaviour by default since it's a bug.

Comment: I don't even know what `\vsize` does; I think it's one of the raw TeX page dimensions, not one of the more nuanced LaTeX ones.  Presumably one should not be setting it at all.

Comment: Oh, I should mention that the same change was made to `\@setfootheight`, so perhaps you should patch it as well, in case people used it too.